# Static block issue

Tags: static-block, blocks

I created 2 static blocks called "message". i want to show one on each store i have. After configuring it correctly im facing an error when i call

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('message')->getIsActive()
```

since it seems not to be calling the correct message block in the store but always the same one. Is there any way to specify the store_id while checking if block is active?

If i dont check if it is active and only show the block with

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('message')->toHtml();?>
```

i get the correct content in each store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
$storeId = 1;
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->load('message');

$isActive = $block->getIsActive();
```

To get the current store id replace `$storeId = 1` from above with

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
```